# jQuery filter not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

The following code triggers a change on a select list if a match to provided text is found.  It works on Chrome, Firefox, but not on Safari:

```
$("#mySelectList option").filter(function () {
  return this.text == 'some text';
}).attr('selected', true).trigger("change");
```

When I debug, this.text is undefined.

- jQuery version 2.1.3
- Safari Desktop version 9.0.1 (Mac)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, it's probably because the `.text` property is undefined.

You should either access [`this.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`$(this).text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$("#mySelectList option").filter(function () {
  return this.textContent == 'some text';
}).attr('selected', true).trigger("change");
```

or

```
$("#mySelectList option").filter(function () {
  return $(this).text() == 'some text';
}).attr('selected', true).trigger("change");
```